# Numerical arrays being loaded before those with letters

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a quiz. Here is the array of questions. The program is supposed to loop through them in order. However, it is first going through all the arrays with numbers and then the ones with letters, as opposed to the order I put them in. Here are the questions:

```
allQuestions = {
    '358670': ['358670', '967723', '214571', '569420', '630697', 0],
    'mbdpf': ['ajcwh', 'xirgb', 'dzelv', 'mbdpf', 'xguqx', 3],
    '637592': ['348335', '921186', '637592', '188551', '391500', 2],
    'xhtjv': ['xhtjv', 'jneez', 'cthul', 'bulwl', 'kqfwc', 0],
    '206471': ['206471', '419643', '366549', '871328', '926142', 0],
    'mwdif': ['bzvai', 'kslgq', 'futgf', 'mwdif', 'sikyp', 3],
    '980924': ['327151', '242777', '708582', '860616', '980924', 4],
    'usiyi': ['iyfod', 'lapwg', 'dqmtt', 'dyvwk', 'usiyi', 4],
    '768898': ['808547', '689143', '875754', '768898', '872606', 3],
    'ziojg': ['xqdiv', 'cyqsu', 'akoed', 'obtpn', 'ziojg', 4]
};
```

Here's the [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zoxPEJ?editors=1000) and here's the entire JS:

```
window.onload = function() {

var questionArea = document.getElementsByClassName('questions')[0],
    answerArea = document.getElementsByClassName('answers')[0],
    checker = document.getElementsByClassName('checker')[0],
    current = 0,

    allQuestions = {
        '358670': ['358670', '967723', '214571', '569420', '630697', 0],
        'mbdpf': ['ajcwh', 'xirgb', 'dzelv', 'mbdpf', 'xguqx', 3],
        '637592': ['348335', '921186', '637592', '188551', '391500', 2],
        'xhtjv': ['xhtjv', 'jneez', 'cthul', 'bulwl', 'kqfwc', 0],
        '206471': ['206471', '419643', '366549', '871328', '926142', 0],
        'mwdif': ['bzvai', 'kslgq', 'futgf', 'mwdif', 'sikyp', 3],
        '980924': ['327151', '242777', '708582', '860616', '980924', 4],
        'usiyi': ['iyfod', 'lapwg', 'dqmtt', 'dyvwk', 'usiyi', 4],
        '768898': ['808547', '689143', '875754', '768898', '872606', 3],
        'ziojg': ['xqdiv', 'cyqsu', 'akoed', 'obtpn', 'ziojg', 4]
    };


    function loadQuestion(curr) {

    var question = Object.keys(allQuestions)[curr];

    questionArea.innerHTML = '';
    questionArea.innerHTML = question;    
  }

  function loadAnswers(curr) {

    var answers = allQuestions[Object.keys(allQuestions)[curr]];

    answerArea.innerHTML = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < answers.length -1; i += 1) {
      var createDiv = document.createElement('div'),
          text = document.createTextNode(answers[i]);

      createDiv.appendChild(text);      
      createDiv.addEventListener("click", checkAnswer(i, answers));


      answerArea.appendChild(createDiv);
    }
  }

  function checkAnswer(i, arr) {

    return function () {
      var givenAnswer = i,
          correctAnswer = arr[arr.length-1];

      if (givenAnswer === correctAnswer) {
        addChecker(true);             
      } else {
        addChecker(false);                        
      }

      if (current < Object.keys(allQuestions).length -1) {
        current += 1;

        loadQuestion(current);
        loadAnswers(current);
      } else {
        questionArea.innerHTML = 'Done!';
        answerArea.innerHTML = '';
      }

    };
  }

  function addChecker(bool) {

    var createDiv = document.createElement('div'),
        txt       = document.createTextNode(current + 1);

    createDiv.appendChild(txt);

    if (bool) {

      createDiv.className += 'correct';
      checker.appendChild(createDiv);
    } else {
      createDiv.className += 'false';
      checker.appendChild(createDiv);
    }
  }

  loadQuestion(current);
  loadAnswers(current);

};
```

Comment: objects have no order. you could use an array for ordered items, or put the keys into an array and use it for accessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript objects provide no guarantees about the order of the elements. The order that you originally put the keys will not necessarily be the order that they are enumerated.

There are 2 main ways to approach this.

1. Create an array separate from the object with the keys in the correct order.

   ```
   var keys = ['358670', 'mbdpf', '637592', 'xhtjv', '206471', 'mwdif', '980924', 'usiyi', '768898'];`
   ```
2. Use an array to store all of the data instead of an object.

   ```
   allQuestions = [
       { key: '358670', data: ['358670', '967723', '214571', '569420', '630697', 0] },
       { key: 'mbdpf', data: ['ajcwh', 'xirgb', 'dzelv', 'mbdpf', 'xguqx', 3] },
       // etc.
   };
   ```

Answer (score 2):

You're iterating over an object, and not over an array. The order of object keys is not fixed - Use an array if you need a specific order:

```js
var obj = {
  a: 'a',
  1: 1,
  x: 'x'
}
console.log('object keys', Object.keys(obj))

var arr = ['a', 1, 'x']
console.log('array values', arr)
```

Answer (score 1):

Objects in JavaScript, like dictionaries in most other languages, do not guarantee order! Arrays do.

Here's how you can wrap your data into an array:

```
allQuestions = [
    { 'name': '358670', 'contents': ['358670', '...'] },
    { 'name': 'mbdpf', 'contents': ['...'] } 
];
```